# Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded, Reconocer ñ en laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy realizando una importación de datos por medio de un archivo excel con ayuda de `"maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1"`, el archivo lo envio por medio de un `ajax`:

```
function subir_excel() {
var dato = new FormData($("#cargar_exceldatosboletasaporteform")[0]);
var route = $('#cargar_exceldatosboletasaporteform').attr('action');
var token = $("#token").val();
$.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token, },
    url:route,
    data:dato,
    dataType:'json',
    type:'POST',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#notificacion_resul_fcdu").html($("#cargador_mensagee").html()); 
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            if(response.errors) {
                $("#notificacion_resul_fcdu").html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"><strong>EL ARCHIVO EXCEL CONTIENE LOS SIGUIENTES ERRORES</strong></div>');
                var myarr = response.data;
                var txt = '';
                myarr.forEach( function(valor, indice, array) {
                    txt = txt + '<li>' + valor + '</li>';
                });
                $("#errors").html(txt);
            } else {
                $("#notificacion_resul_fcdu").html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>BOLETAS DE APORTE REGISTRADAS SATISFACTORIAMENTE!</strong></div>');
                $('#cargar_exceldatosboletasaporteform').trigger("reset");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.location.href = '/porcotwo/public/liquidation/ballots';
                }, 3000);
            }
        } else
            $("#notificacion_resul_fcdu").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>'+response.msn+'</strong></div>').fadeIn(200).delay(4000).fadeOut(300);

    },
    error: function(response){          
        $("#notificacion_resul_fcdu").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>'+response.msn+'</strong></div>').fadeIn(200).delay(4000).fadeOut(300);
    }
});
}
```

y la envió a una función que es algo larga pero por politicas de la comunidad lo publico:

```
public function postGuardarExceldatosboletaaporte(Request $request) {
    try{
        $errors = collect([]);
        $archivo = $request->file('doc_excel');
        $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        $nombre_original = $timestamp. '-' .$archivo->getClientOriginalName();
        $r1 = Storage::disk('archivos')->put($nombre_original,  \File::get($archivo) );
        $ruta = storage_path('archivos') ."/". $nombre_original;
        if($r1) {
            Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($ruta, function($hoja) use ($errors){
                $iii="";
                foreach($hoja->get() as $index => $fila){
                    $fila = $this->convertNumbers($fila);
                    $nombre_socioinput  = strtolower($fila->socio);
                    $nombre_empresanput = strtolower($fila->empresa);
                    $registradosocio = DB::table('socios')
                        ->where('razon_social', 'ILIKE', ''.$nombre_socioinput.'%')
                        ->orderBy('razon_social','ASC')->first();

                    $registradoempresa = DB::table('sitios')
                        ->where('nombre', 'ILIKE', ''.$nombre_empresanput.'%')
                        ->orderBy('nombre','ASC')->first();

                    if(isset($registradosocio) == null){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El socio '.strtoupper($nombre_socioinput).' no se encuentra registrado en el Sistema.');

                    }

                    if(isset($registradoempresa) == null){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': La empresa '.strtoupper($nombre_empresanput).' no se encuentra registrado en el Sistema.');

                    }


                    if(!$this->validarMes($fila->fechaingreso)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': La Fecha Ingreso '.$fila->fechaingreso.' no tiene el formato YYYY-MM-DD');

                    }

                    if(!$this->validarMes($fila->fechatransaccion)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': La Fecha Transaccion '.$fila->fechatransaccion.' no tiene el formato YYYY-MM-DD');

                    }
                    if(!is_numeric($fila->pn)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El peso neto '.strtoupper($fila->monto).' no parece ser un numero');

                    }
                    if($fila->leyag!='' && !is_numeric($fila->leyag)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': La ley de plata '.strtoupper($fila->leyag).' no parece ser un numero');

                    }
                    if($fila->leyzn && !is_numeric($fila->leyzn)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': La ley de zing '.strtoupper($fila->leyzn).' no parece ser un numero');

                    }
                    if($fila->leypb && !is_numeric($fila->leypb)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': La ley de plomo'.strtoupper($fila->leypb).' no parece ser un numero');

                    }
                    if($fila->valorbs==0){
                        if(!is_numeric($fila->totaldescuento) && !is_numeric($fila->montoneto)){
                            $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El total descuento '.strtoupper($fila->totaldescuento).' no parece ser un numero');    
                            $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El monto neto '.strtoupper($fila->montoneto).' no parece ser un numero');    
                            $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El importe bruto '.strtoupper($fila->valorbs).' no parece ser un numero');    
                        }else{
                            if(!is_numeric($fila->montoneto)){
                                $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El monto neto '.strtoupper($fila->montoneto).' no parece ser un numero'); 
                            }else{
                                if(!is_numeric($fila->totaldescuento)){
                                    $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El total descuento '.strtoupper($fila->totaldescuento).' no parece ser un numero');    
                                    $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El importe bruto '.strtoupper($fila->valorbs).' no parece ser un numero');    
                                }else{
                                    $fila->valorbs=$fila->montoneto+$fila->totaldescuento;
                                    $iii=$iii.' '.($index+2).',';
                                    $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El importe bruto '.strtoupper($fila->valorbs).' fue calculado');    
                                }

                            }   
                        }   
                    }
                    if(((float)$fila->rm)!=0 && !is_numeric($fila->rm) ){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': rm '.$fila->rm.' No parece ser un numero');    
                    }
                    if(((float)$fila->cns)!=0 && !is_numeric($fila->cns)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': cns '.$fila->cns.' No parece ser un numero');    
                    }
                    if(((float)$fila->comibol)!=0 && !is_numeric($fila->comibol) ){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': comibol '.$fila->comibol.' No parece ser un numero');    
                    }
                    if(((float)$fila->fedecomin)!=0 && !is_numeric($fila->fedecomin)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': fedecomin '.$fila->fedecomin.' No parece ser un numero');    
                    }
                    if(((float)$fila->fencomin)!=0 &&  !is_numeric($fila->fencomin)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': fencomin '.$fila->fencomin.' No parece ser un numero');    
                    }
                    if(((float)$fila->senaricom)!=0 && !is_numeric($fila->senaricom)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': senaricom '.$fila->senaricom.' No parece ser un numero');    
                    }
                    if(((float)$fila->wilstermann)!=0 && !is_numeric($fila->wilstermann)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': wilstermann '.$fila->wilstermann.' No parece ser un numero');    
                    }
                    if(((float)$fila->cooperativa)!=0 && !is_numeric($fila->cooperativa)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': cooperativa '.$fila->cooperativa.' No parece ser un numero');    
                    }


                    if(!is_numeric($fila->totaldescuento)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El total descuento '.strtoupper($fila->totaldescuento).' no parece ser un numero');

                    }
                    if(!is_numeric($fila->montoneto)){
                        $errors->push('FILA '.($index+2).': El monto neto'.strtoupper($fila->montoneto).' no parece ser un numero');

                    }
                    if ((isset($registradosocio)) && (isset($registradoempresa))) {
                        $valoradmin = number_format(((number_format((str_replace(",", "", $fila->valorbs)), 2, '.','')) * 0.05), 2, '.', '');
                        $valuefondocoopera = number_format((str_replace(",", "", $fila->cooperativa)), 2, '.', '');
                        $fondocuval = number_format(($valuefondocoopera-$valoradmin), 2, '.', '');

                        DB::table('planillas')->insert([
                            'fecha_ingreso'     =>  $fila->fechaingreso,
                            'fecha_transaccion' =>  $fila->fechatransaccion,
                            'sitio_id'          =>  $registradoempresa->id,
                            'socio_id'          =>  $registradosocio->id,
                            'lote'              =>  $fila->lote,
                            'peso_bruto'        =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->pn)),3,'.',''),
                            'ley_plata'         =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->leyag)),2,'.',''),
                            'ley_zinc'          =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->leyzn)),2,'.',''),
                            'ley_plomo'         =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->leypb)),2,'.',''),
                            'importe_bruto'     =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->valorbs)),2,'.',''),
                            'regalia_minera'    =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->rm)),2,'.',''),
                            'caja_salud'        =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->cns)),2,'.',''),
                            'comibol'           =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->comibol)),2,'.',''),
                            'fedecomin'         =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->fedecomin)),2,'.',''),
                            'fencomin'          =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->fencomin)),2,'.',''),
                            'senaricom'         =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->senarecom)),2,'.',''),
                            'wilstermann'       =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->wisterman)),2,'.',''),
                            'cooperativa'       =>  $valuefondocoopera,
                            'total_descuento'   =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->totaldescuento)),2,'.',''),
                            'monto_neto'        =>  number_format((str_replace(",","", $fila->montoneto)),2,'.',''),
                            'admin'             =>  $valoradmin,
                            'custodia'          =>  ($fondocuval > 0) ? ($fondocuval) : 0,
                            'user_id'           =>  \Auth::user()->id,
                            'created_at'        =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            'tipo'              =>  $fila->tipo
                        ]);
                    }
                }
                //aqui
            });
            return response()->json([
                    'success'   =>  true,
                    'errors'    =>  true,
                    'data'      =>  $errors,
                    'msn'       => "errores de base"

                ]);
            if(count($errors) > 0) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success'   =>  true,
                    'errors'    =>  true,
                    'data'      =>  $errors,
                    'msn'       => "errores de base"

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'success'   =>  true,
                    'errors'    =>  false,
                    'msn'       => "SIN errores de base"
                ]);
            }
        } else return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'msn'       => "NO se almaceno nada"
        ]);
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'msn'       => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Todo funciona de maravilla**, hasta que en el archivo excel le envio un dato con la letra **ñ**, donde me arroja la siguiente excepción:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Intente cambiar el `contentType` de mi `ajax` por:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Pero en ese caso me arroja otra excepción

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

que a mi paracer es mas rara.

Como no encontré solución acudo a su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizá sería de gran ayuda que especifiques dónde es el error, en medio de tu largo código. Las *políticas*  del sitio no exigen siempre que se publique todo el código, lo que se pide es que el interesado muestre el código relevante, especialmente la parte donde está dando error. Por ejemplo, deberías mostrar cómo le estás pasando los `headers` al JSON. Deberías decir si el problema es introduciendo esos datos en una base de datos o simplemente mostrándolos en pantalla. Si es en la base de datos, deberías indicar qué codificación tiene la base de datos y la tabla implicada...

Comment: @A.Cedano, la verdad no lo sé, no se donde da el error ya que todo funciona correctamente cuando los datos no contienen la Ñ. Ahora mismo estoy revisando linea a linea para ver donde es que se **atora**, valga el termino, en caso lo encuentre lo publico.

Comment: Al lado del mensaje *`Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`*  supongo que te indica también la línea donde está ocurriendo el error. [La documentación dice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#json-responses) que cuando usas `json` no necesitas ponerle el content type, que lo hace por defecto. No conozco casi nada sobre Laravel, pero este tipo de problemas con juegos de caracteres erróneos suele estar a un nivel profundo: en el origen de los datos o en la configuración misma de Laravel o del servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano, Edite la pregunta para poder mostrar como encontré el error, lo revise en el `console` del navegador, y aun asi no me dice la linea de error en mi codigo. pero ya estoy borrando el `try-catch` para obtener mas informacion.

Comment: No veo el error por ningún lado. ¿Podrías adjuntar el mensaje de error completo en la pregunta **en forma de texto, no de imagen**?

Comment: @A.Cedano, Bueno encontre el error, al paracer  `strtolower` y `strtoupper` solo trabajan como caracteres **UNICODE** y no asi con **UFT-8** asi que tube que cambiar esa funcion por mb_strtoupper y mb_strtolower respectivamente.

Comment: Yo haría una prueba poniendo esto al principio del script `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` y probaría de nuevo a ver qué pasa. Si funciona significa que no tienes el juego de caracteres que deberías tener en el servidor lo cual te puede traer problemas en otros escenarios.

Comment: ¿Trataste de ponerle un `utf8_encode()` a la variable que no está codificada adecuadamente?